# JAVA - String contains char letter. Possible to check?

Tags: java, string, char, contains

I am trying to make a method called `Baller(String str, char chr)` which should return a boolean if the word contains the character. In the main method I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Balling ball= new Balling ();
    System.out.println( ball.contains("Baller", 'a'));
    System.out.println( ball.contains("Baller", 'A'));
}
```

What I did was this but it did not work:

```
public boolean contains(String str, char chr ) {
    if(str.length() == chr) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

What could be the problem?

**ANSWER**

```
public boolean contains(String str, char chr ) {

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            if(str.charAt(i) == chr)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `str.length()` with a `char`?

Comment: @Tom I have check that thread and it wasn't the same as I was looking for because I already have a main method which I should continued with.

Comment: So you compare the length of the string (6) with 'a' ?

Comment: @dognose As you see. im kinda new at this. I was thinking more like all the letters in string compare if there is a char letter in the string.

Comment: @Thrillofit123 If you have a `main` method or not is not the point here. The point is how you can check if a single character appears in a given string. And the linked question answers how you can fix your `contains` method.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that string length is compared to character value:

```
str.length() == chr
```

What you should use if the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) String method

```
public boolean contains(String str, char chr) {
  return str.indexOf(chr) != -1;
}
```

Comment: This worked. It was really simple. But I bet there is another way. but this is much more easier. but if you have time. could you explain it easier for me. I read the documentation and I did not understand full. but I would appreaciate if you could tell me like in a basic step by step :)?

Comment: Other solution would be to convert String to character array and compare each character to given one. Above solution uses `indexOf(char)` method which finds the character in the string and return its position. If character is not found then value '-1' is returned. So any index but `-1` indicates that the string contains that character.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if the length of the String is equal to some char. This will perhaps work if your String is of length zero and your character == 0 or perhaps if your String is of length one and you compare it to the character with the numeric value of 1. In other words: Almost never.

You never return false. So all your string contain all your characters.

String has an `indexOf( character )` method. use that. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29).